# Insert ArrayList in a row of SQL Database

Tags: android, sql, database, arraylist

In my Recipes diary I've got 3 classes, Recipe.class:

```
public Recipe(String title, String firstImage, String secondImage, String thirdImage, String instructions, int targetPeople, int time, int calories, ArrayList<Ingredient> ingredients, ArrayList<Tag> tags) {

    this.title = title;
    this.firstImage = firstImage;
    this.secondImage = secondImage;
    this.thirdImage = thirdImage;
    this.instructions = instructions;
    this.targetPeople = targetPeople;
    this.time = time;
    this.calories = calories;
    this.ingredients = ingredients;
    this.tags = tags;
}
```

Ingredient.class:

```
public Ingredient(String ingredient_name, int quantity) {

    this.ingredient_name = ingredient_name;
    this.quantity = quantity;
}
```

and Tag.class:

```
public Tag(String tag_name) {

    this.tag_name = tag_name;

}
```

When I save a new Recipe, I use two for cycles to store tags and ingredients and each of them is added to the corresponding ArrayList<> (to link more ingredients and tags to the same recipe) like this:

```
for (int c=0; c < countTags; c++) {
           childChipView = (Chip) chipTagGroup.getChildAt(c);
           childTextViewTag = childChipView.findViewById(R.id.chip_item);
        childTag = childTextViewTag.getText().toString();
        newTag = new Tag(childTag);
        dbHelper.insertTag(newTag);
        tags.add(newTag);
    }

    // ingredients fields settings
    for (int d=0; d<countIngredients; d++) {
        childViewIng = parentIngredientLayout.getChildAt(d);
        childTextViewI = childViewIng.findViewById(R.id.ingredientsField);
        childTextViewQ = childViewIng.findViewById(R.id.quantityField);
        childIngredient = childTextViewI.getText().toString();
        childQuantity = Integer.parseInt(childTextViewQ.getText().toString());
        newIngredient = new Ingredient(childIngredient, childQuantity);
        dbHelper.insertIngredient(newIngredient);
        ingredients.add(newIngredient);
    }
```

After, I store in the three corresponding tables of my DB (RECIPE_TABLE, INGREDIENT_TABLE, TAG_TABLE). My problem is, how can I store the two ArrayLists<> inside **RECIPE_TABLE**? I want, i.e., in the same row of that table, the title, instructions, time, calories, etc. and also the two ArrayLists

Comment: By definition ArrayList would be another table  in db(with one-to-many relationship) ... of course you may serialize ArrayList and store it as string but this would be awkward

Comment: So you suggest me to create a RECIPE_INGREDIENT table and a RECIPE_TAG table to associate the ArrayLists to the same Recipe?

Comment: `RECIPES (ID, Name, ...)` `TAGS(ID, Name,..)` `INGREDIENTS(ID, Name,..)`  `RECIPE_TAGS(RecipeID, TagID)` `RECIPE_INGREDIENTS(RecipeID, IngredientID)` ... thats how most programmers would do this with relational database

Answer (score 1):

You should not insert a whole array in a row because that violates the 1NF, try to split it into 2 tables